# oracle regexp_instr in pl/sql doesn't work

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I'm having a clob with pl/sql code inside.
I have to check if there is no exit command inside at the end.

So the following is not allowed:

> Some code ...
> exit

Or

> Some code ...
> exit;

Or

> Some code ...
> exit
> /

But the following is allowed:

> Some code ...
> exit when ...
> Some code ...

Or

> Some code ... 
> Some other code ... -- If this happens than exit
> Some code ...

I've tried with the following piece of code, but that doesn't work:

```
if regexp_instr(v_clob, chr(10) || 'exit[;]?[^[[:blank:]]]', 1, 1, 0, 'i') != 0 then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two many square brackets, and you aren't matching line end; this works with your examples:

```
regexp_instr(v_clob, chr(10) || 'exit(;)?([^[:blank:]]|$)', 1, 1, 0, 'i')
```

As you want to match at the start of a line it would be a bit simpler (and possibly safer for catching both LF and CRLF/LFCR) to do:

```
regexp_instr(v_clob, '^exit(;)?([^[:blank:]]|$)', 1, 1, 0, 'im')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed746110b75d6cf3af08a2415aa7e630) showing your sample values in a CTE and your original result plus the output of both of these options.